# How to call the constructor when all the methods in a class are static?

Tags: c++, static, constructor

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839647/462608

> Use the static initializer:
>
> ```
> public class MyClass
> {
>     static {
>     //init
>     }
> }
> ```

Can something similar be done in C++?
Actually, I need to initialize some variables, but I don't want to create an object.

Comment: Why use a class? Why not just wrap your members in a namespace and use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the variables are `static` members, not only are you able to initialize them, but you **must** initialize them.

There's no direct equivalent of Java initializer lists, but something similar can be done calling a function to initialize a static member:

```
class X
{
    static bool x;
}

bool foo()
{
    //initialization code here
}

bool X::x = foo();
```

This is for cases with intense logic. If all you want is to initialize `static` members, just do it similar to `X::x`.

> Actually, I need to initialize some variables, but I don't want to create an object.

If the variables are outside the class, initialize them directly (don't need calling code for that).

If the variables are `static` members of the class, use one of the above approaches.

If the variables are non-`static` members, they simply don't exist without an object.

Comment: well, thanks for info, but in this particular question, I was taling about normal members. I want the initialization function to be called only once, that's why talked of having a constructor.

Comment: @AnishaKaul members exist for each instance of the class, so you want only the first one that's created to be initialised? This makes no sense.

Comment: `so you want only the first one that's created to be initialised?` Where did I say that? @SethCarnegie

Comment: @SethCarnegie It makes sense if we're talking about singleton pattern... but I wonder if it's the case. For the question itself, the static members of a class doesn't belongs to any instance of the class (they belong to all instances), so doesn't make sense to initialize it on the ctor. They must be initialized *outside* the class as suggested on other answers.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster A singleton is an instance.

Comment: @AnishaKaul "normal" members (I assume you mean non-static) don't exist without creating an object. Pure and simple...

Comment: @AnishaKaul from the link you posted (some logic in the initialization of the member), I'd go with the method approach. The method will be called when initializing `X::x`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, singleton is an instance, and static members does not belongs to any specific instance... I dont know if I'm misunderstanding the OP question I'm just wondering about if the singleton pattern suits the OP requeriments.

Comment: I realize that I shouldn't have used the word "member". My fault. Let me think on the design more, and then respond. Thanks Luchian.

Comment: `If the variables are outside the class, initialize them directly (don't need calling code for that)` But, then, wouldn't I have to make them global? (for initializing outside function)

Comment: @AnishaKaul a static member is a global anyway :)

Comment: Luchain, can a static member be accessed "directly" in any function by anyone?

Comment: @AnishaKaul if it's public, yes.

Comment: There is a confusion it seems. I am talking about the static member declared inside a class.

Comment: @AnishaKaul a public static class member can be accessed from anywhere without an object. This is valid for Java as well.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables of a class are initialized in .cpp file:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
   static void f1();
   static void f2();
private:
   static int a1;
   static int a2;
   static int a3;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
   int MyClass::a1 = 7;
   int MyClass::a2 = 8;
   int MyClass::a3 = MyClass::a1 + MyClass::a2;

   void MyClass::f1()
   {
      a1 = 7;
   }
   void MyClass::f2()
   {
      cout << a2 << endl;
   }
```

---

If you want non trivial initialization of static member variables - group them in inner class with constructor:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
   static void f1();
   static void f2();
private:
   struct Data {
      Data();
      int a1;
      int a2;
      int a3;
   };
   static Data data;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
   MyClass::Data MyClass::data;
   MyClass::Data::Data() : a1(0), a2(0), a3(0)
   {
      // it is just an example ;)
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
      {
         a1 += 2;
         s2 += 3;
         a3 += a1 + a2;
      }
   }

   void MyClass::f1()
   {
      data.a1 = 7;
   }
   void MyClass::f2()
   {
      cout << data.a2 << endl;
   }
```